# Can I get a field from a list of maps using a variable name instead of a specific field name

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of maps **(bText)** and the map of field names include **(kjvtext, nasbtext, esvtext)** string fields.

I have another preferences variable: **String bVersion = "esvtext";**

I want to access the map field **bText[index].esvtext** **when the bVersion field contains "esvtext"** and field bText[index].nasbtext when the bVersion field contains "nasbtext".

I've tried several combinations of code such as:

```
Text(bText[index].bVersion)  
Text(bText[index].[bVersion])  
Text(bText[index]."$bVersion")...
```

I've finally resorted to:

```
     xText = (bVersion == "kjvtext")
                    ? verselist[index].kjvtext
                    : (bVersion == "nasbtext")
                        ? verselist[index].nasbtext
                        : (bVersion == "esvtext")
                            ? verselist[index].esvtext
                            : "bVersion version error\n",
```

Seems like there would be a simpler way to code this?

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is bText[0] is of type Map? If so, you can do bText[index][bVersion].

Comment: switch statement?

Comment: tried bText[index][bVersion] but did not work.  I need to provide working code example . Will do that soon.

Comment: My solution shown is about as long as a switch statement. I needed to use this in ten places, so was looking for a more concise piece of code.  For now, I put this in a separate function and call it from the 10 places. Thanks.